# Silverlight video player not working on chrome (V44)

Tags: silverlight, iis, video-streaming

We have an internal video portal on our company. we built it using IIS smooth streaming and Silverlight player on clients. now users can't play the videos on chrome (it was work before)

Chrome Version: 44.0.2403.130 m

Comment: There's no actual question here; please make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight Plugin uses **NPAPI** that was deprecated by Chrome since version 42

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en

In the last part of the article show how you can temporarily enable NPAPI plugins:

> If you must use a NPAPI plugin, there’s a temporary workaround that will work until Chrome version 45 is released later in 2015:

1. Open Chrome.
2. In the address bar at the top of the screen, type chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
3. In the window that opens, click the link that says Enable under the Enable > NPAPI flag.
4. In the bottom left corner of the page, click the Relaunch Now button.

> After the release of Chrome version 45, you’ll need to use an alternate web browser to load content that requires a NPAPI plugin.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is there any solution

Comment: Besides the temporary workaround it isn't, as google states, if you want to keep using this kind of plugins you have to open your site on another browser. But I think Firefox it's also deprecating the API soon. Maybe you could try to use Chromium Portable Version 41 [Chromium Portable](http://crportable.sourceforge.net/)